# Insert a record into multiple Table using JPA

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa

I have three entities namely

1. product
2. product details
3. stock
4. category
   reference is given below

when I try to get the details of product it works fine when I try to save it shows below error in the console

```
2020-08-12 13:17:22.279  WARN 18612 --- [nio-9002-exec-1] .c.j.MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter : Failed to evaluate Jackson deserialization for type [[simple type, class com.eMart.main.entity.Product]]: com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.InvalidDefinitionException: Cannot handle managed/back reference 'defaultReference': back reference type (java.util.List) not compatible with managed type (com.eMart.main.entity.Product)
```

My question is how to add the product into the database and how did I need to optimize my entities

**Input**

```
{
        "skuId": "2",
        "category": {
            "categoryId": 2,
            "categoryName": "food"
        },
        "description": "cow milk",
        "stock": {
            "stockId": 1,
            "inventoryCount": 5,
            "selfCount": 5
        },
        "productDetails": [
            {
                "productDetailId": 1,
                "cost": 10.0,
                "currency": "inr",
                "expiryDate": "2020-08-11T18:30:00.000+00:00",
                "supplierCode": 1
            }
        ]
    }
```

**controller method**

```
@PostMapping(value = "/test")
    public ResponseEntity<Product> test(@RequestBody Product product) throws Exception {
productRepositry.save(product);
        return new ResponseEntity(productRepositry.findAll(),OK);

    }
```

```
@Getter
@Setter
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@ToString
@Entity
public class Product {
    @Id
    @Column(name = "SKU_ID")
    String skuId=null;
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "category_id")
    @JsonManagedReference
    Category category;

    @Column(name = "description")
    String description=null;

   @JsonManagedReference
    @OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name = "stock_id", referencedColumnName = "id")
    Stock stock=null;

    @JsonManagedReference
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "product", fetch = FetchType.LAZY,
            cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    Set<ProductDetails> productDetails;
}
```

```
@Getter
@Setter
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@ToString
     @Entity
    public class Stock {
    @Id
    @Column(name = "id")
    Integer stockId;
    @Column(name = "inventory_count")
    Integer inventoryCount;
    @Column(name = "self_count")
    Integer selfCount;
    @JsonBackReference
    @OneToOne(mappedBy = "stock",cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    Product product;
    }
```

```
@Entity
@Getter
@Setter
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor

public class Category {
    @Id
    @Column(name = "category_id")
    Integer categoryId;

    @Column(name = "category_name")
    String categoryName;



    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "category", fetch = FetchType.LAZY,
            cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JsonBackReference
    List<Product> product;

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Category{" +
                "categoryId=" + categoryId +
                ", categoryName='" + categoryName + '\'' +
                ", product=" + product +
                '}';
    }
}
```

```
@Getter
@Setter
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@ToString
@Entity
public class ProductDetails {
    @Id
    @Column(name = "id")
    Integer productDetailId;
    @Column(name = "cost")
    Double cost;
    @Column(name = "currency")
    String currency;
    @Column(name = "expiry_date")
    Date expiryDate;

    Integer supplierCode;

    @JsonBackReference
    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    Product product;
}
```

Comment: Can you share the save method controller code?

Comment: Test that your entities implement the Serializable class

Comment: MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter this exception will be thrown when the spring api response back to user. Check object you are returning it should be Product rather than ProductDetails. your db details should have been updated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you have missed adding `@JoinColumn` on `Product` in `ProductDetails` entity

```
@JsonBackReference
@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinColumn(name = "SKU_ID")
Product product;
```

Also, you can try be removing @JsonManagedReference from `Category` or `Stock`

Comment: It throws <br/> ``` WARN 5340 --- [nio-9002-exec-6] .c.j.MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter : Failed to evaluate Jackson deserialization for type [[simple type, class com.eMart.main.entity.Product]]: com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.InvalidDefinitionException: Cannot handle managed/back reference 'defaultReference': back reference type (java.util.List) not compatible with managed type (com.eMart.main.entity.Product)
`` `<br/> after I added this<br/>  ```@JsonBackReference
    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "SKU_ID") 
    Product product;```

Comment: Yes, you need to add same, Have you tried adding @JoinColumn(name = "SKU_ID")?

Comment: It throws this Exception  2020-08-12 19:13:17.117  WARN 20008 --- [nio-9002-exec-1] .c.j.MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter : Failed to evaluate Jackson deserialization for type [[simple type, class com.eMart.main.entity.Product]]: com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.InvalidDefinitionException: Cannot handle managed/back reference 'defaultReference': back reference type (java.util.List) not compatible with managed type (com.eMart.main.entity.Product)

Comment: Could you try by removing `@JsonBackReference` from `Stock ` entity

Comment: after removing all ```@JsonBackReference``` and ```@JsonManagedReference``` it works but when I try to retrieve data it goes infinitely

Comment: Don't remove all just remove it from `Stock ` entity

Comment: I found that by removing ```@JsonManagedReference``` above the ```Category category;``` it works fine can you please explain why it happens

Comment: Actually it is not able to find the appropriate relations between Category and Product

Comment: please change the question into correct format if there is any error